# WooCommerce return get_total() price with two decimals

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, price

Hi I am implementing one payment gateway plugin but have a problem. It shows an error and they said it is because total amount of cart and total amount of a price website is sending for them is different. And it is because they are getting it without decimal numbers for ex. in cart it is **519.00** and they are receiving just **519**.

This plugin gets cart total by `$order->get_total()` function. Is there any method to make function `get_total()` take order price already with *.00*? or if it is *519.5* to make it *519.50* and so on ?

Changing a function in their plugin might work too but I tried other like `WC()->cart->total` but it shows the totals without decimals too.

Comment: Something like `number_format($order->get_total(), 2, '.', '');` ?

Comment: Or use the `money_format()` PHP function and set your locale. For example, I would do: `setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');` and then 
`echo money_format('%i', $order->get_total());`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> WooCommerce has an inbuilt function for this
>   [`wc_format_decimal()`](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_format_decimal/)

Usage:

```
wc_format_decimal( $order->get_total(), 2 );
//or
wc_format_decimal(WC()->cart->total, 2 );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Never knew of this function!

Comment: actual I had a custom function [like this](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_api_ordersget_order/) in my plugin with return full order details for an API, so while do that I came to know this.

Comment: Great, this worked! @TyBailey `number_format($order->get_total(), 2, '.', '');` worked like a charm too. Thank You so much :)

Comment: Glad to here. Always better to use a built in function though :)

Comment: Yeah probably. But my clients cannot wait no more to pay me their money so I will stay with this quick fix:))